# SQL Date Time Automation

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

Good morning,

I'm in the process of trying to remove some of the manual entry in several queries that retrieve a weekly volume of results that have been transmitted through our interfaces. Namely the date time function and several case functions. I wanted to handle the date time first since the case statements don't need to be updated on a weekly basis, only when a new customer is added.

In the past we have been manually editing the data to select the last seven days worth of data.

Example:

```
    WHERE (MessageReceivedDateTime >= '12/23/15 05:00' 
    AND MessageReceivedDateTime < '12/28/15 05:00')
```

I was able to use the proposed code below to retrieve the last 7 days worth of data in our database and it seems to have some values missing on one of the days. I assume this is because I do not have the time offset in the query.

Proposed:

```
    (MessageReceivedDateTime between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE())
```

Part of the goal of updating this was to ensure that we didn't need to manually edit the date/time on a weekly basis. I did a Google search and searched the forum but didn't see anything that was specific to this question. Any additional help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

I would also like to apologize in advance if I selected tSQL incorrectly, my SQL training has all been on the job and we have both Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I run the above queries in Management Studio and believe them to be tSQL.

---- Edit to provide final solution ----

```
    DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = (DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate())-7));
    DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME = DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate()));
   SET @StartTime = DATEADD(hh,(-dbo.fn_GetUTCOffset(@StartTime)),@StartTime);
   SET @EndTime = DATEADD(hh,(-dbo.fn_GetUTCOffset(@EndTime)),@EndTime);

    WHERE MessageReceivedDateTime >= @StartTime
           AND MessageReceivedDateTime < @EndTime
```

In my particular case the only thing I have to worry about on the last day is to make sure to account for my UTC offset. Which I handled with the -dob.fn that we have set up. It will add 5 or 4 depending on the time of year.

Comment: Which values seem to be missing

Comment: Frisbee, I compared the two queries and the between DateAdd left out about 5,000 results on the first day of the query. I would have expected the numbers to be closer to spot on. Though I think that Steven's explanation of the Getdate function using the datetime was substracting 7 days but leaving it as early morning and what I was hoping to retrieve was the entire days values to compare if both queries were working similarly.

Comment: But you were not even retrieving the whole day with > 12/23/15 05:00

Comment: Frisbee, normally in our case we use the 05:00 for the UTC offset which is apparently midnight right now, I assumed without that offset it was going to return the entire day, not sure why I thought that to be honest. Which explains my earlier comments on Gordon's thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GETDATE function returns a DATETIME that is for NOW. Subtracting 7 days, as you did, will return with the date of 7 days ago, but the time of now.

*EXAMPLE:*
    **NOW**:     2015-12-30 12:37:45.143
**DateAdd - 7**: 2015-12-23 12:37:45.143

If you would like a specific time of the day, then you will have to do a little bit more work.

```
DECLARE @MyTime TIME = '05:15'  --This can be changed to whatever time you would like.
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @MyTime)
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @MyTime)
```

It can be used in where clause in your query like

```
  (MessageReceivedDateTime between @StartTime and @EndTime)
```

Comment: Curiously `GetDate()` is treated as a [runtime constant function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) within a query. ([Ref.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/03/01/when-a-function-is-indeed-a-constant.aspx)) It is often clearer to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed. This is more important across multiple statements, as in a stored procedure, where the value may change from one statement to the next.

Comment: @Steven, thank you for the assistance. I went with a variation on your answer to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your second query by converting to `date` to remove the time component:

```
(MessageReceivedDateTime between DateAdd(day, -7, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) and 
                                 CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
)
```

However, I wouldn't use `between` for this.  Something more like:

```
(MessageReceivedDateTime >= DateAdd(day, -7, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
 MessageReceivedDateTime < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
)
```

I'm not sure what the boundaries are on the values, so you might want to add or subtract "1".

Comment: Using the 2nd code gets me an extra day it seems, instead of pulling in 7 days it's giving me a bit of time from the day prior, in this case the 22nd. However for the other 7 days the totals match what I'm expecting.

Comment: @J.E.Flint . . . Could there be a timezone issue in how the datetime is stored in the column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff we do have a function to offset for daylight savings when we're querying but currently all of our data time is stored in UTC date/time.
I believe I just need to make use of a command to only grab from midnight to the end of the 7 days instead of the time associated to now.